# EF Update-database generating error "Impossible to load the file or the assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I run the command update-database on package manager console, I have the code below that causes
Impossible to load the file or the assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its depedencies. The file can not be found.

```
try
{
    var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(x => !x.IsDynamic)
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && 
   p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract).ToList();

    return allTypes;
} catch(Exception ex)
{
    var logger = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<ILogger>();
    logger.Error("Erreur lors du parcours des Assemblies ", ex);
    var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    if (typeLoadException != null)
    {
        var loaderExceptions = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
        foreach (var loaderException in loaderExceptions)
        {
            logger.Error($"loaderException : {loaderException}");
        }  
    }
    return new List<Type>();
}
```

Can someone help me how to solve it please ?

Comment: What’s that error in English

Comment: "The specified file can not be found."

Comment: You probably have a mismatch version in either your web.config or package.config or both.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the error in english

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try a nuget restore / nuget update / dll mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. In my EF Projetct, there is an "App.config" that references "Microsoft.Owin" BUT in the project references the nuget was missing. So I installed the nuget "Microsoft.Owin" with the correct version and now it's working.

That's why the error was "the specified file can not be found"